# How to set value of backing bean at page refresh

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Can any body suggest me How to set the values of attributes in the backing bean as null as soon as the page is refreshed .??

I tried setting values in the constructor of the bean . but since the bean is called multiple times the values are initialized at each call . Which doesnt solve the problem for me .

So I need a way where the values are set as null when the page is refreshed so .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the initialization within a post contructed method of your backing bean :

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    // attributes to be initialized at every refresh
    name = null;
}
```

Comment: It's used to indicate that the method has to be invoked just after the managed-bean's construction. While your managed-bean is `@RequestScoped` for example, that method should be invoked at every refresh of the page. In other side, there's `@PreDestroy` which is used to indicate that such method has to be invoked just before the managed-bean's destruction.